# R: Change RasterBrick dimensions from TXY to XYT

Tags: raster, r

I am having difficulties in `R` getting climate data from a `netCDF` file into the right format for further analysis. I am working with gridded global data on Standardized Precipitation Index (downloaded from [here](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.IRI/.Analyses/.SPI/%28.SPI-CAMSOPI_1-Month%29//var/parameter/interp/SOURCES/.NOAA/.NCEP/.CPC/.CAMS_OPI/.v0208/.mean/.prcp/yearly-climatology/X/periodic/setgridtype/pop/Y/%28-65%29/%2875%29/RANGE/DATA/-3.1/3.1/RANGE//long_name/%28SPI%29/def/%5BT%5Daverage/0.2/masklt/0.2/flagge/mul/SOURCES/.WORLDBATH/.bath/0/masklt/0/flagge/mul/datafiles.html) and want to aggregate the monthly values for each grid-cells to an annual average.

Now the issue is that in the file the data is organised as TXY, where T are the number of months since January 1960 and X and Y are longitude and latitude respectively. As a result, when I load the file into `R` with,

```
library(raster)
spi<-brick("data.nc")
```

I get the following dimensions:

```
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 144, 441, 63504, 58  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 2.5  (x, y)
extent      : 228, 669, 0, 360  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : data.nc 
names       : X.66.25, X.63.75, X.61.25, X.58.75, X.56.25, X.53.75,... 
degree_north: -66.25, 76.25 (min, max)
varname     : aprod
```

So annoyingly, the monthly observations are on the columns whereas the latitude coordinates are on the layers. Which I don't find very useful and makes processing the data rather difficult.

Therefore I wondered, if there is a way in which I can change the dimensions to a more conventional format? With the data of interest on the layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular data source (IRI data library) allows reordering in its language, e.g. append

[ X Y ] REORDER

[data link](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.IRI/.Analyses/.SPI/(.SPI-CAMSOPI_1-Month)//var/parameter/interp/SOURCES/.NOAA/.NCEP/.CPC/.CAMS_OPI/.v0208/.mean/.prcp/yearly-climatology/X/periodic/setgridtype/pop/Y/(-65)/(75)/RANGE/DATA/-3.1/3.1/RANGE//long_name/(SPI)/def/%5BT%5Daverage/0.2/masklt/0.2/flagge/mul/SOURCES/.WORLDBATH/.bath/0/masklt/0/flagge/mul/%5B/X/Y/%5D/REORDER/#expert)

Comment: I didn't dare to venture into `Expert Mode`. Many thanks.